# Bootstrap popover is not appearing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm facing strange issue. Bootstrap's popover **is not appearing** in my application.

Of course I am **initiating** popover in .js file (to be clear this file is also included into head section).
`$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();`

This is how my simplest popover link looks like:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
```

By the way bootstrap's tooltips are working correctly.

---

**Update - head + body sections**

```
<head>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('css\bootstrap.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="{{URL::to('js\less.min.js')}}"></script>
    @include('includes.header')
    @yield('content')
    <script src="{{ URL::to('js\jquery-1.12.4.js')}}"></script>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js'>
    <script src="{{ URL::to('js\app.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::to('js\bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    rest of the code...
</body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Is your initialization before or after the jquery/boostrap includes? And is it wrapped in a document.ready? usually these types of initialization are in the footer.

Comment: Yes it's wrapped in document ready function, firstly I include JQuery and then Bootstrap.

Comment: Try putting the initial code before closing body (`</body>`), so it will be after content. Probably it can't find the element, since it haven't been parsed yet.

Comment: @debute That will only be if the OP wasn't using document ready. OP, which version of boostrap are you using?

Comment: @zerohero yea right, when I was writing my comment, I haven't seen that information :)

Comment: With popover's you have to click to make it show up, unlike tooltips, are you saying onmouseover it's not working? or on click?

Comment: Of course I click on it.  Bootrstrap version -  v3.3.6, JQuery - v1.12.4

Comment: you are using anchor , go with button . anchor default action is implementing first

Comment: @zan nope. check http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_popover_pos&stacked=h

Comment: @forexknight please include your <head>

Comment: Maybe it's because of lack of `data-placement` attribute? BTW here's working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qune48d8/  but there is higher jQuery version included

Comment: With button it's also not working. Something must block it. Hmm...

Comment: if you initialisation is correct then it might be your cache.

Comment: It's 100% not cache. I'm clearing it always when I make changes.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Unfortunately you solution is also not working. I've tried many examples, I'm not asking question untill I do not check questions from other users.

Comment: @forexknight you are including all your javascript in the body tag instead of the head tag? why?

Comment: @zerohero If you do this page content is loaded faster and then scripts are loaded. User cannot run scripts when there's no page content. It's logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move:

```
<script src="{{ URL::to('js\app.js')}}"></script>
```

Below:

```
 <script src="{{ URL::to('js\bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
```

And make sure all  tags appear in the  and not the

Because your script tags are in the body, the DOM needs to fully load first before it can execute. I'm surprised your console doesn't report an error.

Comment: Yep, the console was clean like a little baby.